# Why does printf behave differently when called from a Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, printf, escaping, quoting

The `printf` program can be used to print binary data, e.g.:

```
$ printf '%b' '\xff\xff'
��
```

If I put this in a Makefile on its own, it works the same:

```
all:
    printf '%b' '\xff\xff'
```

```
$ make
printf '%b' '\xff\xff'
��
```

However, if I want to do anything else on the same shell invocation in the Makefile, for example to redirect it to a file, or just printing something else afterwards, then although the command printed by Make doesn't change (suggesting it's not an escaping issue), but the output changes to a backslash followed by an "x" followed by a double "f", twice:

```
all:
    printf '%b' '\xff\xff'; printf 'wtf?\n'
```

```
make
printf '%b' '\xff\xff'; printf 'wtf?\n'
\xff\xffwtf?
```

What is going on here? Why do the two `printf`s in one line behave differently than a single `printf`?

Comment: `printf` is a built-in in many shells; you likely are using `bash` as your interactive shell, but `make` is using your system default shell, which may not be `bash`.  Hence, two different `printf` commands.

Comment: @chepner but how does that explain the different `printf` behaviour between the two `Makefile`s?

Comment: This is wild speculation, but I suspect there is some sort of optimization being applied by `make` that causes the first example, as a simple command, to be executing a third option, the actual binary `printf` (found in `/usr/bin`, perhaps), rather than a shell. In your second example, the `;` forces `make` to use a shell to execute the shell command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@chepner is on the right track in their comment but the details are not quite right:

> This is wild speculation, but I suspect there is some sort of
> optimization being applied by `make` that causes the first example, as a
> simple command, to be executing a third option, the actual binary
> `printf` (found in `/usr/bin`, perhaps), rather than a shell. In your
> second example, the `;` forces `make` to use a shell to execute the shell
> command line.

Make always uses `/bin/sh` as its shell, regardless of what the user is using as their shell.  On some systems, `/bin/sh` is bash (which has a builtin `printf`) and on some systems `/bin/sh` is something different (typically `dash` which is a lightweight, POSIX-conforming shell) which probably doesn't have a shell built-in.

On your system, `/bin/sh` is bash.  But, when you have a "simple command" that doesn't require a shell (that is, make itself has enough trivial quoting smarts to understand your command) then to be more efficient make will invoke that command directly rather than running the shell.

That's what's happening here: when you run the simple command (no `;`) make will invoke the command directly and run `/usr/bin/printf`.  When you run the more complex command (including a `;`) make will give up running the command directly and invoke your shell... which is bash, which uses bash's built-in `printf`.

Basically, your script is not POSIX-conforming (there is no `%b` in the POSIX standard) and so what it does is not well-defined.  If you want the SAME behavior always you should use `/usr/bin/printf` to force that always to be used.  Forcing make to always run a shell and never use its fast path is much trickier; you'll need to include a special character like a trailing `;` in each command.

Comment: I think the optimization is implementation-specific (probably GNU `make` here). I don't see any mention in the POSIX spec of a command line being executed in any way other than by a shell (but then again, the POSIX spec is long and I certainly haven't read the entire thing thoroughly).

Comment: Is there a way to run the program `printf` instead of the shell builtin, without specifying its full path?

Comment: It is true that the optimization is something GNU make does, it's not part of POSIX.  The theory is that if you have a conforming system and a conforming makefile, it should be impossible to tell the difference between using the fast path and the slow path.  If your system and/or makefile are not conforming then all bets are off :).

Comment: See my final paragraph above.  You can add a semicolon to the end of every `printf` to force it to not use the fast path.

Comment: @MadScientist my question is if there is a way to use the `printf` program (i.e. what i would get by writing `/usr/bin/printf` explicitly), without hardcoding the `/usr/bin` path in the Makefile. So currently in my real Makefile I have  `(/usr/bin/printf '%b' '\xff\xff'; cat $<) > $@` as a make rule. How can I rewrite that without hardcoding `/usr/bin` but keeping the external (non-shell-builtin) `printf`?

Comment: I understood the question.  The answer is there is no way to ensure you're using `/usr/bin/printf` without actually using `/usr/bin/printf`.  This is not a make issue, this is a shell issue.  If you run `printf` in a shell that has a built-in `printf`, then the built-in `printf` will be used.  It doesn't matter if it's make that invokes the shell, or a shell script you wrote, or whatever.  If you stick to POSIX-standard behaviors then it won't matter because the built-in version and `/usr/bin` version will behave identically.  If you use non-standard behavior, then...

Comment: FWIW, on my Ubuntu GNU/Linux system, both the shell built-in printf and also /usr/bin/printf behave the same way (they both print the glyph, not `\xff`).  So I think the incompatible behavior is even deeper than that, in that /usr/bin/printf also doesn't work the same way across systems.  It's possible that if you write `\printf ...` (note leading backslash) then it will not use the shell built-in; at least some shells follow that convention.

Comment: No that's @chapner's comment that the answer already refers to.